# Rate Limiting Done right in distributed microservices?

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, resilience4j

I have an spring boot application where I am using resilency4j dependency to implement some basic rate limiting .
I do not like what has been implemented and want to propose a better approach that is more flexible .
In scouring for a better option I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m64SWl9bfvk) which seems like exactly what I want

The video in summary is a dynamic rate limiting with features such as

- use backpressure to determine server load instead of hardcode value
- Can autoscale with number of instance of server created in realtime
- uses percentage to allocate resources and lets other clients borrow resources if available.

I am honestly not doing the video justice check it out if have time.

However I have not been able to find any implementation of it anywhere.In demo it seems the presenter is using `ngnix` but I could not find any documentation of the feature he shows.

I strongly feel that in a cloud centered,autoscalable world rate limiting cannot be done at a service level and has to be on a higher level of abstraction just cant find a solid example to implement it.Any resource pointing will be appreciated.